# How do I create an audio player in HTML5 from an audio?

Tags: html, html5-audio, jplayer

i found a couple HTML5 audio examples:

jQuery plugin:
http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/latest/demo-01.htm

This site uses the above jQuery plugin for a stream:
http://wfmu.org/html5/player.php

This one uses streams from scratch:
http://www.trygve-lie.com/blog/entry/html_5_audio_element_and

Another tutorial:
http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

As long as the stream has Ogg Vorbis source and MP3, it should be good.

How could I use JavaScript to create a channel-picker that would use a different source for the audio stream upon changing the channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply use jquery or regular javascript to remove the old  tag from the dom, and create a new  tag, set the source to the new mp3 file (from your track listing selector), and start it playing.
i.e.

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'loading.ogg');
audioElement.play();
```

Some pretty decent examples [here](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/introduction-to-the-html5-audio-tag-javascript-manipulation/)

Comment: Word. Yeah, thanks, I think I'll do that. I'll try to just update the inner `<source>` tag first to see if that works. If not, I'll change the whole `<audio>` element.